# What does a HTML Form Button execute?

Tags: php, html

When clicking the "Submit" button in a HTML form, what code is executed? Is all of the HTML (and PHP) code on the page re-executed, or just the code inside of the  tags?

**EDIT**

The code below is exectued on the form.

```
<buttoninput type="submit" value="Login"> Login </button>
```

**EDIT 2**

If the form is the follow, and the following button is on the inside. What will happen? Will the whole page be re-executed, or will just the form be re-executed?

```
<form action="stackoverflow/posts/28333195" method="post">
  <buttoninput type="submit" value="Login"> Login </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Generally it executes a specified action (GET or POST) to the server with some predetermined data and you cannot count on the reexecution of code on the page.  But, you cannot count that code WILL NOT be executed again, either.

Comment: It depends: if there's a form, an action, javascript, hacked browser, unicorns.

Comment: Whatever you tell it to execute.

Comment: Optional reading https://github.com/alex/what-happens-when :)

Comment: Forms are not executed, code is. When you submit a form, it just calls the `action` page with the HTTP method set to `get` or `post` as appropriate. The whole page is executed, but it will often have `if` statements in it to see what it should do depending on the circumstances. Often you'll see logic like "if the method is 'post' and button 'save' was pressed, call this method".

Answer (score 2):

Absent of JavaScript event handlers interfering with the normal operation, the form data will be encoded as per the encoding specified in the `enctype` attribute (for a POST request) or placed in a query string (for a GET request) and the data will be submitted to the URL specified by the `action`.

This will load a new page.

Any server side code associated with the URL will run (with any branching statements (e.g. `if`s) directing program flow as normal).

Full details of [the client side of form submission](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#form-submission-0) are in the HTML specification.

Answer (score 1):

At a very high level, this is what happens:

1. The user clicks the submit button.
2. Button `onclick` handler JavaScript code will execute.
3. Form `onsubmit` handler JavaScript code will execute.
4. The form will be submitted to the URL specified in `<form action="...">`.
5. Any server-side PHP logic will execute.

This ignores several steps that might happen: form validation, server-side redirects, additional JavaScript event handlers, etc.

Comment: Assuming the URL in `<form action="...">` points to a PHP script, that script will be executed on the server.